# Custom visual Force page in customer portal

Tags: apex, visualforce, customer-portal

I'm creating a custom visual force page to download files stored in salesforce "Content".

This page will be included in the customer portal.

Do you know if the portal user (after the login) will be able to download the content's file without purchase features?
i have found .
http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_content.htm

but it isn't clear for me. I don't want all the content feautures in a tab.I want just to create links to download files stored in salesforce content.

Thanks in advantage for any advice.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, customer portal users can download without having a content feature license. They do need the "View Content on Portals" user permission, however. But then as long as you provide the right link in your custom VF page, they should be good to go. We've done similar in custom portals. The format for the link is:

https://[yoursubdomain].secure.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/[ContentVersionId]?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER

Comment: Thanks Tim for your support.Is there some problem about the permission to give to the portal user to download the content's file? Because i have found solution like this:    1. Create a site
2. Create a public group
3. Associate the site's guest user to the public group
4. Associate the public group to a workspace
5. Upload a file to the workspace (which creates a ContentDocument with a corresponding ContentVersion record)
6. Get the ContentVersion ID and plug it into this URL: I'm scared to get the message Insufficient Privileges.Thanks a lot

Comment: That pretty much sums it up! With all of those steps complete, your portal user should be able to download the content just fine.

Comment: Have you followed the same steps? your page was a visual force tab in the customer portal or a site?Thanks again

Comment: Actually not quite. Earlier you mentioned portal users (after login) and for portal users, we've done this very thing with success. But I just noticed you mentioned the site guest user in your previous comment and that I do not believe you can do. The force.com site's guest user will not be able to download content. But replace your step 3 with "Associate the portal user with the public group" and you should be good to go.

Comment: Looking at a sites guest user's details, there is a "Salesforce CRM Content User" setting, so checking that and adding the guest user to the public group may work, too.